# CCMoveTo duration / speed issue

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

Some help would be most appreciated.  Sprite movement based upon a heading that is given from a touch on the screen.  Sprite moves as expected but I am unable to vary the speed, no matter what value I use for currentSpeed.  This is in the update method of the sprite.  Thanks in advance.

```
    // Distance between two points (Distance formula, Pythagorean Theorem c^2=a^2+b^2, so d=sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
    // Duration (time = distance / rate)

    CGPoint adjustedPosition;
    adjustedPosition.x = position_.x - sinf(heading);
    adjustedPosition.y = position_.y - cosf(heading);

    float distance = CGPointDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(adjustedPosition, position_);
    float duration = distance / currentSpeed;

    position_ = adjustedPosition;

    [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration position:position_]];
```

Comment: is this in an 'update' method (or ccTouchMoved) , or a fire-and-forget method until the next touch ?

Comment: It is in the sprite's update method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use a moveto or for that matter any action in an update method. Instead, compute the position , something like this:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) dt {

    // _velocity in points per second.
    // heading should be in ccw notation, 0 on x axis, RHS

    float deltaX = dt * _velocity * cosf(heading);
    float deltaY = dt * _velocity * sinf(heading);
    CGPoint adjustedPosition = ccpAdd(self.position, ccp(deltaX,deltaY));
    self.position = adjustedPosition;
}
```

or something similar. This will ease out any variance id dt, for which the only thing you can bet on is that it wont be constant ; but the physics should be right.

Comment: So I did end up using a variant of your implementation (yours is cleaner, and well, it works :) ), but it still doesn't explain why mine wouldn't work.  I have never read that you can not use actions in a scheduled updater.  Would be interested in knowing the "why" behind that.  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for distance:

```
float distance = ccpLength(ccpSub(adjustedPosition, position_));
```

Comment: No joy.  The distances were pretty similar between your method and mine.  I am thinking that there is a minimum duration with CCMoveTo because increasing the speed does shorten the duration, just doesn't have any effect on the sprite.  Thanks for the response though.